# phpmyadmin: Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm sorry to be asking a common question but I have gone through all the existing answers to no avail. Fresh setup on CENTOS 7
Mysql 8
phpmyadmin 4.4.15.10
PHP 5.4.16

default config setup

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';          // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';          // Path to the socket - leave blank for default socket
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';    // The php MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;       // Use compressed protocol for the MySQL connection
                                                    // (requires PHP >= 4.3.0)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '';          // MySQL control user settings
                                                    // (this user must have read-only
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '';          // access to the "mysql/user"
                                                    // and "mysql/db" tables).
                                                    // The controluser is also
                                                    // used for all relational
                                                    // features (pmadb)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';    // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?
```

Mysql startup log

```
2020-08-08T22:17:47.303766Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 12712
2020-08-08T22:17:47.315318Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-08-08T22:17:48.285337Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-08-08T22:17:48.507535Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-08-08T22:17:48.840424Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-08-08T22:17:48.841150Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
```

I have created a fresh mysqluser from command line and verified login on CLI. No matter what I do I get the "Cannot login to MySQL server" on the browser.

I have tried changing port to 33060 and host to 127.0.0.1
I'm at a loss and suspect I am missing something simple. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect now that it is a php library mismatch. I need older php because we are housing legacy software. I will begin looking at php 5.4 with mysql 8. Any direction appreciated.

Comment: Yes issue was php/mysqli 5.4 doesn't play well with MySQL 8. My legacy software needs the older PHP so I installed MySQL 5.7 as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem with Manjaro. Installing net-tools fixed it for me.
Do you have this?
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/net-tools-2.0-0.25.20131004git.el7.x86_64.rpm.html